# The enabled languages setting in Liferay portal-ext.properties file doesn't seem to work

Tags: liferay, liferay-7

I am trying to limit the languages to only English.  We have not yet translated any of our content, so having Liferay able to change it's language isn't helpful, and has caused some issues when user's accidentally stumble across URLs that have an alternate language in them.

So we want to limit the language to only English.  I have set the following in portal-ext.properties:

```
locales.enabled=en_US
```

However, if I then access with a different language in the url ('iw' for example), the page is still translated.

So, am I not understanding what this setting does?  Does it only limit the languages available in the language picker or something?  I would appreciate any suggestions as this has become a frequent occurrence for our users as Google has also indexed some of our pages in different languages.

We are using Liferay 7 GA 7.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tested this on my liferay-ce-portal-tomcat-7.3.5-ga6-20200930172312275 server:

I used these properties in my portal-ext.properties file:
locales=en_US
locales.enabled=en_US
locale.prepend.friendly.url.style=0

When the portal started up, I visited these sites and indeed the pages were not translated as you requested:
http://localhost:8080/iw
http://localhost:8080/de
Please let me know if you had another use case in mind

Some useful resources:
https://issues.liferay.com/browse/LPS-65042
https://docs.liferay.com/portal/7.3-latest/propertiesdoc/portal.properties.html

Comment: Interesting.  I will test ASAP and see if those additional properties do the trick, and accept the answer if it does.  Thank you.

Comment: This, along with locale.use.default.if.not.available=true worked in 7.3 GA6.  However, it does not work on our existing 7.0 GA7 servers.
Since we will be upgrading to 7.3 is the very near future, this will be fine, and your answer led me to testing 7.0 vs. 7.3 so I consider it solved.  Thanks.

Comment: In case anyone is interested, we weren't able to ever get this working, but as we have upgraded to 7.3 it is no longer relevant.

Answer (score 0):

for me helped adding
locales=en_US
locales.enabled=en_US
to this path bundles/portal-setup-wizard.properties, bundles/portal-ext.properties

Comment: Thanks for the response.  Those were the properties we initially tried.  I think it's just a 7.0 issue as we are now running 7.3 and it is working fine.